# How to attach a file as an attachment in email using SendGrid?

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid, email-attachments, sendgrid-api-v3

I am wanting to attach a file as an attachment using SendGrid and C# - I have the code below which runs but the `response.StatusCode` that is returned is

> BadResponse

How do I alter this code so that the file is attached and an email sent successfully?

```
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
var listAtta = new List<FileAttachment>();
emailProducts.Select(o => o.tp).ToList().ForEach(o =>
{
    string file = o.ProductPdf;
    var fileBytes = FileToByteArray(o.ProductPdf);
    if (fileBytes != null && fileBytes.Count() > 0)
    {
        listAtta.Add(new FileAttachment
        {
            FileData = fileBytes,
            FileName = o.ProductPdf
        }); ;
    }
    msg.AddAttachment(o.ProductPdf, fileBytes.ToString());
});

var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
var success = response.StatusCode;
```

Comment: What is the type of `msg` here?

Comment: if I hover over msg it shows msg | {SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.SendGridMessage} - is that what you are after?

Comment: Are you able to send the email successfully without attachment?

Comment: Yes, I can send email no problem w/o attachment.  Adding the attachment it will not send and gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to base64 encode it
msg.AddAttachment(o.ProductPdf, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) )